# Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragreva.FragA

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm learning how to use fragments.. i came across this error, and haven't been able to rectify it.. tried a lot of combinations.. i tried searching online for this..couldn't solve it still..

when i copied this complete project, in my older project with fragment.. it worked completely fine without any error.. 
i thought there was some error with the support library, so i removed and added the library again, which is functional in the WORKING PROJECT without any issues.. but to no success..
Thanks.

```
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragrevb/com.example.fragrevb.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.example.fragrevb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 11 more
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragreva.FragA: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:572)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:540)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 21 more
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.fragreva.FragA
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:562)
11-03 08:22:47.336: E/AndroidRuntime(1608):     ... 24 more



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.fragrevb.MainActivity" 
android:background="#00BBFF">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.fragrevb.FragA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="com.example.fragrevb.FragB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />
```

this was the code.. i have rectified the error. It was my bad.
While adding the fragments in the activity_main.xml.. i had 2 fragments with the same name already created in another project.. So i had added those fragments(from other project) in this activity(current project).. before it was, **android:name="com.example.fragreva.FragB"** and **android:name="com.example.fragreva.FragA"**(which was wrong).. i changed it to **android:name="com.example.fragrevb.FragB"** and **android:name="com.example.fragrevb.FragA"** ..hence the error.. Lesson leant. Thanks everyone for trying to help out ! cheers.

Comment: Seems like the xml corresponding to fragment FragA isn't expanding correctly. Like you said, it's likely that you are having trouble with a library but you should post the xml file anyway, if you really want help.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i got the answer..it was a silly mistake..but a lesson learnt..
i have edited it above..thanks for replying ! :)